# Rails Advanced Constraint pass variable from Routes to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, routes

Given

```
# routes.rb
get ':friend_slug', to: 'friend#show', constraints: FriendConstraint.new

# friend_constraint.rb
def matches?(request)
  friend = Friend.find_by(slug: request.params['friend_slug'])
  friend.present?
end
```

Since I already looked up and have the `friend` in my routing constraint, how do I save/pass my variable `friend` for controllers to avoid double lookup?

Currently, I'm doing the exact same line, `Friend.find_by(slug: request.params['friend_slug'])` in the controller.

Comment: there are workarounds to get the query run only once and save the result, but it might be better to explore options to cache using tools such as memcached or redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution.

Create a class `Current`, And here you can set any variable.

in `app/models/current.rb`

```rb
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :friend
end
```

in constraint, you can set `Current.friend`

```rb
# routes.rb
get ':friend_slug', to: 'friend#show', constraints: FriendConstraint.new

# friend_constraint.rb
def matches?(request)
  friend = Friend.find_by(slug: request.params['friend_slug'])
  Current.friend = friend ## here I set friend
  friend.present?
end
```

Now, you can use `Current.friend` in any `controller`, `model`, `view` or may be in other places too.

Comment: Wow thanks for this! The documentation even states it's for this exact purpose of carrying data globally around on a per request basis.

Answer (score 1):

There's no clean way to carry a variable from the constraint to a controller.

The dirty way is setting an instance variable directly on the `request` object.

```rb
# friend_constraint.rb
def matches?(request)
  friend = Friend.find_by(slug: request.params['friend_slug'])

  return false if friend.blank?

  request.instance_variable_set('@namespace_friend', friend)
end

# friends_controller.rb
...
friend = request.instance_variable_get('@namespace_friend')
...
```

`@namespace_` so you never collide with a proper request variable.

Definitely do not recommend for production, but it was an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding extra key to `request.params`? Like this:

```
# friend_constraint.rb
def matches?(request)
  friend = Friend.find_by(slug: request.params['friend_slug'])
  request.params[:friend] = friend 
  friend.present?
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but like my solution of adding it to the `request` object directly, it dirties a space that's not really meant to have it. The accepted solution using `ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes` was actually designed for this very use case.

Comment: Caution from official docs:
`It's easy to overdo a global singleton like Current... Current should only be used for a few, top-level globals, like account, user, and request details. The attributes stuck in Current should be used by more or less all actions on all requests. If you start sticking controller-specific attributes in there, you're going to create a mess.`
In my case I only use it for one action in one controller. So, not sure Current is a good option there.